# Extract pixel values form a multispectral (B1-B6) raster image using a shape file mask

Tags: pandas, raster, mask, geopandas, rasterio

I want to extract the pixel values form a raster image by a mask (polygon shape) and save each pixel value bands as a pandas dataframe

```
import rasterio
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
mask = gpd.read_file('/disco02/emurillo/Documentos/metodologia_usuev/calval_v2g.shp')


values_band1 = []
values_band2 = []
values_band3 = []
values_band4 = []
values_band5 = []
values_band6 = []

with rasterio.open(r'rep_pncm_2018_lluvia_C2_b2b7_int16.tif') as src:
    
    values_band1 = (rasterio.mask.mask(src, mask.geometry, crop=True)[0][0])
    values_band2 = (rasterio.mask.mask(src, mask.geometry, crop=True)[1][0])
    values_band3 = (rasterio.mask.mask(src, mask.geometry, crop=True)[2][0])
    values_band4 = (rasterio.mask.mask(src, mask.geometry, crop=True)[3][0]) 
    values_band5 = (rasterio.mask.mask(src, mask.geometry, crop=True)[4][0])
    values_band6 = (rasterio.mask.mask(src, mask.geometry, crop=True)[5][0])


df = pd.DataFrame({'band1': values_band1,
                   'band2': values_band2,
                   'band3': values_band3,
                   'band4': values_band4,
                   'band5': values_band5,
                   'band6': values_band6})
df = pd.concat([df, mask], axis=1)
```

I get this error

---

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_1506850/2883401435.py in <module> 47
> values_band1 = (rasterio.mask.mask(src, mask.geometry,
> crop=True)[0][0]) 48     values_band2 = (rasterio.mask.mask(src,
> mask.geometry, crop=True)[1][0]) ---> 49     values_band3 =
> (rasterio.mask.mask(src, mask.geometry, crop=True)[2][0]) 50
> values_band4 = (rasterio.mask.mask(src, mask.geometry,
> crop=True)[3][0]) 51     values_band5 = (rasterio.mask.mask(src,
> mask.geometry, crop=True)[4][0])
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 0):

`rasterio.mask.mask()` always returns a tuple of length 2, where the first element is the array of values.

Because of that this should fix your problem:

```
with rasterio.open(r'rep_pncm_2018_lluvia_C2_b2b7_int16.tif') as src:
    values, transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, mask.geometry, crop=True)
    values_band1 = values[0]
    values_band2 = values[1]
    ...
    values_band6 = values[5]
```